# Bayesian improper prior on product of parameters

Tags: bayesian, prior

I'm interested in two sets of variables coming from bivariate normal distribution.

$X_i$'s iid ~ N($\mu_x$,$\sigma^2$)
$Y_i$'s iid ~ N($\mu_y$,$\sigma^2$)
and Cov(Xi,Yi)=$\sigma_{xy}^2$.
Now $\mu_x$= $\mu$ + $\gamma$
and $\mu_y$= $\mu$ + $\lambda$*$\gamma$.

In this case, can I use prior on only one of the parameters of $\mu$'s?
That is, can I use prior on $\lambda ~ \text{Uniform}(a,b)$
and obtain posterior distribution of $\lambda |X,Y$?

(Updated)
If I have to impose prior to all parameters.
Can I impose a constant prior to $\mu$ and $\gamma$? Will my choice of constant affect the posterior distribution of $\lambda$ significantly? (Or maybe very large uniform prior on $\mu$ and $\gamma$ as well?)

Comment: No, you have to have a prior on all the unknown parameters.  Note also that a Uniform(a,b) distribution is not improper, as it integrates to 1.  Nothing prevents you from putting improper priors on the other parameters, though.

Comment: @jbowman I've updated my question. Could you please answer that?